# Further customizing Material UI components?

Tags: material-ui

Is there any way to style the attributes of Material UI components that are not accessable through `props`?

For example, the `Checkbox` component has in my opinion a too large margin between itself and the label, which I would like to decrease, or perhaps I want to make the label on the left, instead of the right.

Is this possible?, if not, it seems like MUI is very restricting

Answer (score 5):

In the documentation of the material-ui, under the section of switches → subsection of checkboxes, you ll find that there are 2 props for overriding the default styles of the component:

1. iconStyle (referring to the style of the checkbox icon)
2. labelStyle (referring to the corresponding label). 
   One solution for your problem would be the following: 
   `<Checkbox name="..." value="..." label="..." iconStyle = {{left: "10"}} />`

   Since the icon has a default relative positioning you can use `left` to bring it closer to the label.